# Incorrect hexadecimal matrix multiplication results

Tags: c++11, hex, codeblocks, matrix-multiplication

matrix 1:

> 0x02  0x03  0x01  0x01
>
> 0x01  0x02  0x03  0x01
>
> 0x01  0x01  0x02  0x03
>
> 0x03  0x01  0x01  0x02

matrix 2:

> 0x63  0x53  0xe0  0x8c
>
> 0x09  0x60  0xe1  0x04
>
> 0xcd  0x70  0xb7  0x51
>
> 0xba  0xca  0xd0  0xe7

These two matrices are multipled in this function:

```
void mul(uint8_t state[4][4])
{
    for(unsigned short i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        state [0][i] = byteProduct(0x02 ,state[0][i]) ^ byteProduct(0x03, state[1][i]) ^ state[2][i] ^ state[3][i];
        state [1][i] = state[0][i] ^ byteProduct(0x02, state[1][i]) ^ byteProduct(0x03, state[2][i]) ^ state[3][i];
        state [2][i] = state[0][i] ^ state[1][i] ^ byteProduct(0x02, state[2][i]) ^ byteProduct(0x03, state[3][i]);
        state [3][i] = byteProduct(0x03, state[0][i]) ^ state[1][i] ^ state[2][i] ^ byteProduct(0x02, state[3][i]);
    }
}
```

In this function I've taken matrix 2 column by column and individually multiplied with the values of the rows of matrix 1. And the value should be replaced in the state matrix.

ByteProduct is defined as:

```
uint8_t byteProduct(uint8_t x, uint8_t y)
{
    uint8_t result = 0, temp;

    while(x != 0)
    {
        if((x & 1) != 0)
            result ^= y;

        temp = y & 0x80;
        y <<= 1;

        if(temp != 0)
            y ^= 0x1b;

        x >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The result should be :

> 0x5f  0x72  0x64  0x15
>
> 0x57  0xf5  0xbc  0x92
>
> 0xf7  0xbe  0x3b  0x29
>
> 0x1d  0xb9  0xf9  0x1a

But the mamtrix resulting from the function is different from this.
Any solutions to this?

Note that these calculations are performed in GF(2^8) field, hence don't try to use `+` and `*` operators, rather `^` is used for `+` operator and `byteProduct()` functions returns the multiplication of `uint8_t`s.

I've performed row x column multiplication.

Comment: Please explain the desired result. I'd expect it to contain either (0x02 * 0x63 + 0x53 + 0xe0 + 0x03 * 0x8c) == 0x450, column x row; or ( 0x02 * 0x63 + 0x03 * 0x09 + 0xcd + 0xba ) == 0x268, row x column.

Comment: Also, do not fill values into one of the matrixes you are still using for calculation. Make a copy of it first or fill a new matrix.

Comment: It would help to make a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch, it is row x column multiplication, and it is not normal hex multiplication through `*` and `+` operators, but calculations are performed in GF(2^8) field, where `+` is `^` (xor) and multiplication is given by function byteProduct, so what you have calculated above is incorrect.

Comment: How about my second comment? Did you try not overwriteing while still using the matrix?

Comment: In order to help me helping you, please provide a [mcve]. With that help by you, it will be easy to demonstrate which of my comments is actually the answer and solution to your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch, it is already the minimal code required to produce the problem, and I can't find any missing details relevant to the problem, so if you have any trouble regarding this just ask I will provide the info

Comment: It is **too** minimal and **not** verifiable, because it is **not** complete. Those blue words are a link. Please click it, read and apply the described idea. At the very least it should compile. [mcve]

Comment: @Yunnosch but there is no more explanation to it, I don't have anything else. All I am asking is where am I going wrong in this way of multiplying matrix where I have accessed second matrix column by column

Comment: Did you read the link? Do you honestly believe that the code you show matches what is described there?

Comment: Do you understand why I ask for an MCVE? It is a tool to efficiently help you. Please do not expect me to invent the whole context and first work on it to make it work and to study how exactly to get your problem recreated. That is supposed to be **your** work. Make the effort to make helping you easy. Usually making an actual MCVE even makes the author aware of the problem. So it really is in your own interest. Please, try. Pretty please.

Comment: Also, I already told you where you are going wrong. But it is a little abstract. So I intend to make a convincing demonstration of how your problem is happening and how to fix it. But I will only do so on the foundation of a MCVE. Please note that the conversation with you already took me more effort than you. I admit there is some little stubbornness here, but you need to understand how StackOverflow works. You may say "I only need this one answer." In that case please realise that the shortest plausible way for you to get one is to just play to my whim and do as I say. If you insist.

Comment: Can you please tell me the things you can't understand, so that I can keep that in mind while editing

Comment: You do not need to explain anything. I do fully understand. I just want you to make an MCVE. Note that asking about a problem during execution of a program, without providing an MCVE is practically a reason for closing your question as off-topic. One of the people with the privilege to decide that your question conflicts with that rule has already voted to close it. I am another one, but did not yet. Instead I decided to help you understand, **before** it gets closed.

Comment: Well @Yunnosch, I have solved it, as you mention not to fill values in array I am still using was the problem, the values were being replaced continuously giving compromised results, thanks.

Comment: OK. In that case I will make an answer, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Note that I consider this an example of an author finding the problem or understanding a short comment while trying to make an MCVE. Welcome to the club of people who made that experience. (This sounds cycnical, but I am serious.)

Comment: In case you want some more reputation: Making an MCVE, even after finding an answer, might be all between you and an upvote or two.

Comment: @Yunnosch, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: No. An MCVE is part of the question and it does not demonstrate the solution. It serves to demonstrate the problem. I.e. the result of the code in your MCVE should be wrong, i.e. be different from the desired result you define in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not fill values into one of the matrixes you are still using for calculation.
Make a copy of it first or fill a new matrix.
Otherwise you will compromise the values you still use for calculation.

E.g.

```
    state [0][i] = byteProduct(0x02 ,state[0][i]) ^ byteProduct(0x03, state[1][i]) ^ state[2][i] ^ state[3][i];
    state [1][i] = state[0][i] ^ byteProduct(0x02, state[1][i]) ^ byteProduct(0x03, state[2][i]) ^ state[3][i];
```

The first line already overwrites the value of `state [0][i]` and then the second line uses it again to calculate the `state [1][i]`.

Comment: Thanks, I was also writing the answer to this question, just so others may know.\

Comment: Making your own answer, once you found the solition to a problem, is absolutely accepted here at StackOverflow. But thanks for granting me the honor.